# Subnetting, how do you find the Ip range , and subnetMask ?

Tags: subnet

If you have Subnet A with a network address of 172.25.100.0 and you need 1100 hosts . You also have Subnet B with a network address of 192.168.105.0 and you need 70 , find the subnet masks, and IP rage for both networks.

I don’t know how do this can someone please explain that process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add an explanation which isn't in bits. For Subnet A you need 1100 hosts, a /24 provides 255 addresses. A /23 provides 512 addresses. A /22 provides 1024 addresses. So we will need a /21 which provides 2048 addresses (2046 usable).

For Subnet B we need 70 hosts. Again, a /24 provides 255 addresses, a /25 provides 128 addresses and a /26 provides 64 addresses. So we will need a /25 with 128 addresses (126 usable).

Answer (score 0):

If you 1100 hosts then you would need atleast 11 bit as a host bit so remaining 21 bit represent your subnet mask. So your subnet mas would be `11111111.11111111.11111000.00000000` which would be `255.255.248.0.`

Similarly for 70 hosts you would need 7 bits for host addresses and 25 bits for network so `255.255.255.128` would be the subnet mask.